# Sending email using Cloud Code and Sendgrid

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-cloud-code, sendgrid

I need to send email from Parse cloud code to user after certain transaction. When I tried with below code it's not working and giving error as below:

```
[Error]: TypeError: object is not a function
at main.js:9:17 (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)
nil
```

Here is the cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("mailSend", function(request, response) {
// using SendGrid's Node.js Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs
var sendgrid = require("sendgrid")("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
var email = new sendgrid.Email();

email.addTo("test@sendgrid.com");
email.setFrom("you@youremail.com");
email.setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
email.setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js");

sendgrid.send(email);
});
```

and here is Swift code to call Cloud code function mailSend:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("mailSend", withParameters: nil) { (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) in
    }
```